# Flutter - returning UploadTask returns TaskSnapshot instead

Tags: flutter

Since last flutter upgrade Flutter 1.22.2

```
  Future uploadImageToStore(path, {String remotePath = "receiptImages"}) async {
    Io.File _image = Io.File(path);
    String fileName = Path.basename(_image.path);
    print("uploadImageToStore " + path);
    if (await _image.exists()) {
      final Reference storageReference =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(remotePath + "/" + fileName);
      final UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(_image);

      return uploadTask;
    } else {
      print("image does not exit");
    }
  }
```

it doesn't return `UploadTask`, instead it returns `TaskSnapshot`

the code that uses this method use the `UploadTask` to set a listener:

```
final UploadTask uploadTask = await this.uploadImageToStore(
    newReceipt['mergedImgPath']['path'],
    remotePath: "receiptMergedImage");

uploadTask.events.listen((event) async {
  this.updateReceiptProgress(event, newReceipt.key, receiptBloc);
});
```

The code used to work on previous release, now it compiles but throw runtime exception:

`Unhandled Exception: type 'TaskSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'UploadTask'`

How can I fix this to work with the new flutter version?

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was changing:

```
return uploadTask;
```

to

```
return Future.value(uploadTask);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

change `uploadImageToStore` to:

```
  Future<TaskSnapshot> uploadImageToStore(path,
      {String remotePath = "receiptImages", void onData(event)}) async {
    Io.File _image = Io.File(path);
    String fileName = Path.basename(_image.path);
    print("uploadImageToStore " + path);
    if (await _image.exists()) {
      final Reference storageReference =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(remotePath + "/" + fileName);
      final UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(_image);
      uploadTask.events.listen(onData);

      return uploadTask;
    } else {
      print("image does not exit");
    }
  }
```

ie add `onData` parameter and use it to to `uploadTask.events.listen(onData);`

use it as follow:

```
final TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await this.uploadImageToStore(
    newReceipt['mergedImgPath']['path'],
    remotePath: "receiptMergedImage", 
    onData: (event) async {
      this.updateReceiptProgress(event, newReceipt.key, receiptBloc);
    });
```

Although it solved the issue, I'm still not sure why the original code stopped working

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this issue too, (this might not work for everybody) what worked for me was adding

```
Future<UploadTask>
```

infront of uploadImageToStore()